# Elasticsearch date range intersection

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing something like the following information in elastic search:

```
{ "timeslot_start_at" : "2013-02-01", "timeslot_end_at" : "2013-02-03" }
```

Given that I have another date range (given from user input for example) I am wanting to search for an intersecting time range. Similar to this: [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) Which outlines that the following logic is what i'm after:

```
(StartDate1 <= EndDate2) and (StartDate2 <= EndDate1)
```

But I'm unsure of how to fit this into an elastic search query, would I use a range filter and only set the 'to' values, leaving the from blank? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: should the user input range be completely 'covered' by the doc timerange, or is it okay they're just partially overlapping?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update: It is now possible to use [date_range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/range.html) data type that was added in elasticsearch v5.2. For an earlier version of elasticsearch the following solution still applies.

To test for intersection, you should combine two range queries into a single query using bool query:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "timeslot_start_at": {
                        "lte": "2013-02-28"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "timeslot_end_at": {
                        "gte": "2013-02-03"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you want to exclude intersecting date ranges from your results? I'd expect "must_not" to work but it's not.

Comment: @Necoras Thanks! Good catch!